# Open - Edit - Save - Loop csv files in a folder with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I will receive a folder with 100+ .csv files and I will need to edit them in the same way. Files have the same structure.
Folder looks like this:
df1.csv
df2.csv
df3.csv
...
df100.csv. I need to open all files - edit them - and then save them as "df1-edited", "df2-edited" and so on.

As per each df the code runns perfectly. I am not sure how to automatically run it through every file and save them accordingly.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')

[Edit steps here]

df.to_csv("df1-edited.csv", index=None, encoding='utf-8-sig', decimal=',')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use a module from the standard-library that works with your operating system.

Essentially, you need to find all the `.csv` files in your folder and iterate over them.

Let's use `pathlib`. This is not tested but something like this should work:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

csv_folder = Path('path/to/csvs')

for file in csv_folder.glob('*.csv'): #create iteratable & iterate on it.
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # do stuff
    new_file_name = file.parent.joinpath(f"{file.stem}-edited.csv")
    df.to_csv(new_file_name, index=None, encoding='utf-8-sig', decimal=',')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Manakin. It does work but it only saves the last df. For some reason it does not loop properly. Any idea?

Comment: @CCRo did you place the last line outside of the for loop?

Comment: Solved! The problem was my [do stuff] code was not indented. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Coming back to this, can you please instruct me on how to save the new files separately in a newly created folder?